# Magento - Prevent cron from running duing an import

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.6

Is there any way to automatically prevent the Magento cron.php from running during an active import? We have a few heavy cron processes and preventing them from running will help speed up our import.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way of doing this is to temporarily remove Magento's `cron.php` (or `cron.sh`) script from your server's crontab. This can be done directly on the server using `crontab -e`, or through cPanel or some other server management interface, depending on your server setup.